# is Google Calendar suitable as backend for a large application

Tags: calendar, scalability, backend, saas

I'm researching an excellent calendar service to host the events to a specific platform; the idea is to use a quick calendar service to host and manage our events.

Since our platform has a frontend, the customer doesn't have direct access to this calendar, instead, he'll use a frontend logic to create and manage events and our backend will link that business logic with a calendar service like Google Calendar service.

Our business logic will separate and organize many customers and different calendars (multi-tenant), allowing multiple customers to have a good experience with scheduling events and each one accessing his own list of events.

Is Google Calendar suitable as a calendar service backend for a large application like that?

Answer (score 3):

After some research, I found that it is possible to use Google Calendar as a backend for my app. You can leverage that using Google Server-To-Server API or "Two-legged OAuth".

- A Google API must be created in Google API panel
- You must take care because Google API has a quota to limit your requests
- If you want more allowance, you can request by contact Google office

More details in:

- https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts

I'll go with my service from scratch. Also, I found a satisfying service.
 - http://calendarserver.org/ (worth a try)

Comment: Than you for looking into this. What did you end up using?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure now how the project is going, but the team started to use and do some tweak with the Calendar Server